# SharePoint Infopath forms giving user not found or is not unique

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath

I am getting an error while submitting a form in SharePoint List through Infopath .The ULS logs are not giving much except this error **"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The user does not exist or is not unique.,"** .Its not happening for a single user and it happening for all the users in the Farm .I already checked the Portal Super user and reader account and they have appropriate permissions on the farm .Any guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: I also checked that all the SharePoint User of group fields are tied only to an individual user and not for multiple selections

Answer (score 0):

Is there some people picker filed in your form?

If yes, please check the property of the people picker in the InfoPath form to see whether it has allowed multiple values, whether people picker control data type is User Type and check if the list is read-only.

You could try to create a new list to test whether the issue occurs.

Comment: Thank you ,Yes it has people picker fields and i have checked and made sure that there is no multiple select and the list is not read only .I have created a new list and it works wit Infopath .But i need to make this list work as Unfortunately this list infopath was developed longtime ago and it has some workflows and others